# How to enable slow query logs in Digital Ocean managed MySql database?

Tags: mysql, performance, digital-ocean

I'd like to enable the 'slow query log' in Digital Ocean managed Mysql database for getting queries in a period ot time and build some performance statistics.
Digital Oceans offers on Query statistics page some statistics, but I cannot export them neither get another informations.
I saw log_output variable is set to 'table' and the slow_log table exists in mysql database.

Is there any way to enable slow query logs in Digital Ocean managed Mysql database?

I tried to set the GLOBAL slow_query_log variable, but it's not possible once I don't have the SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege. Maybe I cannot have this privilege because it's a managed database.

Comment: Does the slow_log table have any rows of data available?  What is the slow_log table name?  Try this, from a MySQL Command Prompt and post the reply, please.  SELECT @@long_query_time;  Thanks